# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException Class 'Comments' not found

Tags: database, laravel, migration, models

My model Comments.php:
I'm not including the class anywhere I just created the model and the migration and nothing works, I am so confused I can't think straight.

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comments extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
            'id',
            'user_id',
            'post_id',
            'comment'
        ];

        public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date)
        {
            $this->attributes['pubslished_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);
        }

        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        }
        public function posts()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Posts');
        }
}
```

And here is my migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCommentsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->text('comment');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('post_id')
                ->references('id')
                    ->on('posts')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('comments');
    }

}
```

Now once I run the command "php artisan migrate:rollback and /or refresh" I get this error code:

> "*[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  Class 'Comments' not found*"

Only way for me to refresh the tables is to manually drop all tables with phpMyAdmin and run "php artisan migrate"

But I don't know if that is healthy.

Comment: Can you test if a route works after migrating? Also, enable debug and check your logs for error description.

Comment: try first do a composer dump-autoload -o and then php artisan migrate:rollback and /or refresh. Also Laravel expects ur model to by in singular "Comment" and ur table plural "comments" if you want to keep your model as "Comments" add protected $table = "comments"

Comment: I don't know why but the "composer dump-autoload -o" command fixed my problems, Care to elaborate how it works? It's an all new command for me :)

Also thanks ;)

Comment: Nope, Doesn't work. I have the files on an USB, And this only happens on this one PC. I'm at school and the error only occurs on this specific PC.

Comment: "I" Found out what was wrong, The row in the migrations table was incorrect as I somehow generated the migration file wrong.

Answer (score 7):

1. `composer dump-autoload`
2. `composer update`
3. Migration file name is in the right format (`YYYY_MM_DD_HHMMSS_filename.php`)

Answer (score 1):

May be your model name will be "Comment" not "Comments". Because laravel uses the plural form of the name fo model as the default database. Such as User model for users table, Comment model for comments table.

Answer (score 1):

Try including `use App/Comments` in your controller file. I hope it will work, and if it dont work then check for any spelling mistake and also double check your **ROUTES** .